# What's the benefit of using "raise ... from ..." in Python 3?

Tags: python

Recently I noticed `pylint` complaining with [error message "raise-missing-from (W0707)"](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) when using a `raise` statement inside an `except` block, but I don't see any difference when adding this to a piece of code. Here's an example without `raise ... from ...`:

```
class MyExc(Exception):
    pass


def calc(n):
    try:
        return n / 2
    except TypeError:
        raise MyExc()


def main():
    calc("foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 7, in calc
    return n / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "foo.py", line 13, in main
    calc("foo")
  File "foo.py", line 9, in calc
    raise MyExc()
__main__.MyExc
```

### With `raise ... from ...`

Now, adding the `... from ...` clause:

```
class MyExc(Exception):
    pass


def calc(n):
    try:
        return n / 2
    except TypeError as exc:
        raise MyExc() from exc


def main():
    calc("foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which give the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 7, in calc
    return n / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "foo.py", line 13, in main
    calc("foo")
  File "foo.py", line 9, in calc
    raise MyExc() from exc
__main__.MyExc
```

### Diff

A diff of the two tracebacks shows only a difference in the message between the two tracebacks. This seems minuscule. I still see the full chain in both cases. So I wonder: what are the *useful/practical* benefits of this?

```
--- a   2020-08-28 13:30:00.762576720 +0200
+++ b   2020-08-28 13:30:04.738544485 +0200
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
     return n / 2
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
 
-During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
+The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "foo.py", line 17, in <module>
@@ -11,6 +11,6 @@
   File "foo.py", line 13, in main
     calc("foo")
   File "foo.py", line 9, in calc
-    raise MyExc()
+    raise MyExc() from exc
 __main__.MyExc
```

Comment: The messages are similar because you reraised in the `try-except` block, if you had left the block and then wanted to get the complete traceback, then `raise ... from ...` would be the way to achieve that.

Comment: The page you linked to has an explanation: *Not using raise from makes the traceback inaccurate, because the message implies there is a bug in the exception-handling code itself, which is a separate situation than wrapping an exception*. If you don't think that's important, then you can configure Pylint to ignore the message. Here's [a thread](https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/ibEOt3A9c2M/m/7qcS82hWDwAJ) on the django-developers mailing list, where they decided not to switch to `raise from`, because the code churn was not worth the change.